# How to zoom in graphs in colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I am able to get an interactive graph in Google colab with the code:

```
!pip install mpld3
%matplotlib notebook
mpld3.enable_notebook()
df.plot(x = 'Time', y = 'Data')
```

but the plot is really small. 
In R you can click on the graph and it will reopen in the new window. Is there a similar method to do this with colab? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

google-colaboratory does not provide any native data visualization, but it does support a variety of third-party visualization packages (matplotlib, altair, bokeh, plotly, etc.) You should look in the documentation of the library you are using to see how to adjust the size of figures.

In your example, you appear to be using pandas matplotlib plotting API. As the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) mentions, you can adjust plot sizes with the `figsize` argument:

```py
df.plot(x='Time', y='Data', figsize=(16, 10))
```

Answer (score 1):

[mpld3](https://mpld3.github.io/) is an interactive module for matplotlib.
You can understand its working [here](https://github.com/sachinmotwani20/Raw-Signal-Processing-Python/blob/master/ZoomGraphGoogleColab.ipynb).

A simplifies answer to the same could be

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mpld3
from mpld3 import plugins

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.grid(True, alpha=0.3)

plt.plot(x, y)
mpld3.display()
```

where x & y are arrays of corresponding axis values.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26098349)

Comment: Added Code content here. Hope that solves the query.